# how can i fill a combobox using a select C#

Tags: c#

I am using the next code.

```
   public void MostrarCombobox(ComboBox cmbIDart)
   {
       Command = "SELECT idArtigoAvaliar FROM dbo.PorAvaliasao WHERE (avaliado = 0) AND (idAutor ='" + Autor.id2 + "')";

       SqlCommand Comm1 = new SqlCommand(Command, Conn);
       SqlDataAdapter data = new SqlDataAdapter(Comm1);

       SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand();

       using (Conn)
       {
           sqlCommand = Conn.CreateCommand();

           sqlCommand.CommandText = Command;

           SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand.CommandText, Conn);

           SqlCommandBuilder scb = new SqlCommandBuilder(sda);

           //Criar uma tabela para receber os dados
           DataTable dTable = new DataTable();

           //Preencher a tabela
           sda.Fill(dTable);

           BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
           bSource.DataSource = dTable;
           cmbIDart.DataSource = bSource;

           Conn.Close();
       }

   }
```

My problem is that when I am starting to call the ComboBox, it shows `System.Data...` and I want them to show the value.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *system.data.(etc)*...? You have to be more specific in general when asking questions =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in your combobox rows look like showing like;

```
System.Data.DataRowView
System.Data.DataRowView
System.Data.DataRowView
System.Data.DataRowView
System.Data.DataRowView
```

You need to set your Combobox [`DisplayMember`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember.aspx) and [`ValueMember`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember.aspx) properties.

If this is not fix your problem, try to make things more clear dynamically.

```
Combobox1.Items.Clear();

string Command = "SELECT idArtigoAvaliar FROM dbo.PorAvaliasao WHERE (avaliado = 0) AND (idAutor ='" + Autor.id2 + "')";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Command, Conn);
cmd.CommandText = Command;

SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read())
{
   Combobox1.Items.Add(dr["idArtigoAvaliar"].ToString());
}
```